# Mediawiki whitelist-type access control based on group and category/namespace

Tags: mediawiki

I'm administrating my company's wiki built using MediaWiki and we are looking to grant access to our customers, but only to the pages within the "Customer" (customer documentation) category, so I'm looking for an extension (or how to do this natively if possible) that will grant read access to only pages within the "Customer" category to registered users not in any group and then grant full access to all pages in the wiki to users who belong to the employee group.  In short:

Anonymous/Unregistered users:

- "Login required"

Registered ungrouped users:

- can read pages in "Customer" category
- cannot read pages not in "Customer" category
- cannot edit pages
- cannot create pages
- etc

Users in Employee group:

- can read pages in "Customer" category
- can read pages not in "Customer" category
- can edit pages
- can create pages
- etc

I have found an extension that comes close, [Restrict access by category and group](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Restrict_access_by_category_and_group), but that employs a blacklist approach meaning that it's far too easy for someone to forget to add a page to a blacklisting category and accidentally expose it to non-employees, so I want something that uses a whitelist approach so that the default behavior is to restrict access.  Is there a way to do this either natively or through an extension?  I'm also open to using namespaces instead of categories.

Answer (score 1):

As the big warning box on top of the extension page you linked says, MediaWiki was not designed for granular read access support. The safe approach is to have separate customer and internal wikis (there are extensions for easy mirroring of content).

If you don't care about that, the [SimpleSecurity](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleSecurity) extension is one example of category-based access control.

Comment: That definitely looks useful, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  From what I'm reading, it looks like all pages would be accessible to customers by default and I need to browse to each page that I don't want a customer to access to restrict it.  Suppose I create a page.  Before I make any changes to the permissions, I'd like it to be inaccessible by default.  Then if the content is safe to show customers, I'd use the 'protect' tab to give read access to customers.  Is that something that SimpleSecurity can do?

Comment: Fair point, don't know if that's possible without writing your own extension.

Comment: Yeah and even that looks like it would be a real pain to do too.  I tried to manually manipulate rights in LocalSettings.php and could never get it to both show an anonymous user "Login required" and a customer user "Permission error" when trying to read any page, so I can't imagine it being easy to write something that do that and grant read rights based on namespace/category on top of that, so I may have no other choice but to create a separate wiki just for the customer documentation.